# Spring Data Redis - @Transactional support on Repository

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data, transactional, spring-data-redis

We're using `spring-boot-starter-parent` 1.4.1 together with `spring-boot-starter-redis` and `spring-boot-starter-data-redis`. We use redis for (a) message passing to an external app and (b) to store some information in a repository. Our redis config looks like this

```
@Configuration
@EnableRedisRepositories
open class RedisConfig {

    @Bean // for message passing
    @Profile("test")
    open fun testRedisChannelProvider(): RedisParserChannelProvider {
        return RedisParserChannelProvider("test_parser:parse.job", "test_parser:parse.joblist")
    }

    @Bean // for message passing
    @Profile("!test")
    open fun productionRedisChannelProvider(): RedisParserChannelProvider {
        return RedisParserChannelProvider("parser:parse.job", "parser:parse.joblist")
    }

    @Bean // for message passing
    open fun parseJobTemplate(connectionFactory: RedisConnectionFactory): RedisTemplate<String, ParseJob> {
        val template = RedisTemplate<String, ParseJob>()
        template.connectionFactory = connectionFactory
        template.valueSerializer = Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<ParseJob>(ParseJob::class.java)

        return template
    }

    //@Bean // for message passing
    //open fun parseJobListTemplate ...

    // no template for repository
```

With this config the message passing is working nicely as well as writing to/reading from the repository. Now I am trying to get `@Transactional` working for communication with the repository, but I have not succeeded so far. I already followed the example config in the [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.7.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis.repositories.usage) and manually enabled transaction support on it:

```
@Bean
open fun redisTemplate(): RedisTemplate<*, *> {

    val template = RedisTemplate<ByteArray, ByteArray>()
    template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true)
    return template
}
```

...but this is apparently not the way to go. Currently, everything written to the repository (in particular during tests) stays there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Transactional` use of Redis repositories is not possible, and I doubt it will work at all.

The reason behind is how Spring Data Redis repository support works:
 [`RedisKeyValueAdapter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisKeyValueAdapter.java#L188-L188) relies on results of [write](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/4c8f1674e4544604dfbd0ebd2a8081196201ccd3/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisKeyValueAdapter.java#L223-L223) and [read](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/4c8f1674e4544604dfbd0ebd2a8081196201ccd3/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/core/IndexWriter.java#L130-L130) operations that are issued while persisting an object.

Redis transactions behave more like deferred batches, so it's not possible to wrap Redis repository support inside a transaction but require a different approach and impose several limitations.

Comment: its quite old post, but can you give us any advice how to manage relational db and redis in single transaction? to rollback both in case of any error